# JQWidgets Tree. Dropping to an empty tree — cannot get the dropped item

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, tree, jqwidget

below is a min working example of the issue I have.

I need to drag items from one tree and drop to another. E.g. from a "toolbox" to the actual tree.

This issue is present if only if the target tree is initially empty.

After dropping to the target tree, I cannot get the corresponing tree item in the on ‘select’ handler, which is triggered on drop. The item does not get the selected (highlighted, colored) state and is not actually selectable.

There is no issue if the target tree contains any single item at the beginning.

Can someone please advise if I’m missing smth?

```js
    $('#jqxTree').jqxTree({
        height: '300px',
        width: '300px',
        allowDrop: true
    });

    $('#btnTree').jqxTree({
        height: '50px',
        width: '100px',
        allowDrag: true
    });

    $('#jqxTree').on('select', function (event) {
        var args = event.args;
        console.log(args.element);
        var item = $('#jqxTree').jqxTree('getItem', args.element);
        console.log(item); // null
        item = $('#btnTree').jqxTree('getItem', args.element);
        console.log(item); // null
    });
```

```html
<link href="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxdragdrop.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxpanel.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxtree.js"></script>

<div id='btnTree'>
    <ul>
        <li>Drag Me</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id='jqxTree'>
    <ul>
        <!-- <li>Single Item</li> --> <!-- try uncommenting this line, so the target tree has some nodes (as opposed to being empty) -->
        <!-- more items can be here -->
    </ul>
</div>
```